# How to solve eslint Errors Dependency cycle via

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

How to solve this eslint error

**Dependency cycle via ../stores/store:30 import/no-cycle** 
I Imported the store like this

```html
import { store } from './store';
export default class UserStore {
constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this);   
  }
 
     // Code

}
```

and the store file

```html
import { createContext, useContext } from 'react';
import { NotistackStore } from './notistackStore';
import UserStore from './userStore';
import AccountStore from './accountStore';

interface Store {
  userStore: UserStore;
  AccountStore:AccountStore;
  notistackStore: NotistackStore;
}
export const store: Store = {
  userStore: new UserStore(),
  AccountStore: new AccountStore(),
  notistackStore: new NotistackStore(),
};
export const StoreContext = createContext(store);
export function useStore() {
  return useContext(StoreContext);
}
```

eslint version eslint-plugin-react@7.31.10
eslint-plugin-react-hooks@4.6.0

Comment: Create a third module.

Comment: how to create third module?

Answer (score 0):

You've imported `store` in a file that also is imported in `store`. Think of it as if you had a dependency A, that you import into a dependency B, but dependency, B is also imported into dependency A. Think of how you can refactor your code, so that the imports are only one-way.